# How to run my node js /expressjs frontent on AWS Amplify?

Tags: node.js, express, aws-amplify

I've deployed my node js app from github to AWS Amplify. However It doesn't work as I have a 404 error.

I think my Amplify.yml is wrong but since I'm not familiar with this service I really don't know what to do :

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build commands
    build:
      commands: []
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: /
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

On localhost, I just need to do `node app.js` to run my app. But I don't know how to build this to make it works on AWS Amplify.

Any Idea ?

Comment: Looking for the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

AWS has official documentation about deploying it.

- https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/api-rest/express-server/q/platform/ios/

> Deploying the service. To deploy the API and function, we can run the
> push command: `amplify push`

Comment: My app is not an api rest for ios. This is an expressjs frontend app so I need to use aws Amplify hosting. The docs is not very clear about my use case.